# How to create a 32 bit red texture byte buffer

Tags: textures, image-processing

I want to make a red texture image buffer. Would anyone help me to make it in right way. I have tried following:

```
std::vector<BYTE> redTexture(w*h*4);
const auto stride = w * 4;
BYTE* buf = redTexture.data();

for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
{
  const auto redValue = Gdiplus::Color::Red;
  memcpy(buf, &redValue, stride);
  buf += stride;
}
```

Comment: What went wrong with your current code? Did you get a compilation or runtime error? Or does it give a different result than expected?

Comment: I could not map the buffer to  ID3D11Texture2D using device context - throws exception

Comment: Including the details of the exception you got inside your question itself will help users searching for similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by doing the following:

```
    CImage m_cImage;
    // create a test image
    m_cImage.Create(w, -h, 8 * 4); // 8 bpp * 4 channel
    auto hdc = m_cImage.GetDC();
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);

    // Create a SolidBrush object.
    Gdiplus::SolidBrush redBrush(Gdiplus::Color::Red);

    // Fill the rectangle.
    Gdiplus::Status status = graphics.FillRectangle(&redBrush, 0, 0, w, h);
    TRY_CONDITION(status == Gdiplus::Status::Ok);
    ....
    // Then saved the m_cImage.GetBits() to bmp file using Gdiplus::Bitmap
    // and my expected texture is found
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Remember to mark your answer as "Accepted" so other users experiencing similar problems can quickly find working solutions. It will also help them if you add some explanation about *why* this works when your earlier approach didn't.